# Why is Emacs syntax highlighting in Gnome terminal affected by terminal colour theming?

Tags: terminal, syntax-highlighting, emacs24

I'm using Emacs 24.3 under Ubuntu 14.04.1. I'd like to use it both via the GTK interface and the Gnome terminal with `emacs -nw`. Unfortunately, the colours for any theme that I use appear slightly different in the terminal.

I've set things up so that under Gnome terminal, `TERM=xterm-256color`. However, I have also customised my terminal colors — "black" is actually `#151515`, "red" is `#DA4939`, etc. Emacs seems to get *close* to displaying the correct colours for each theme, but is never quite correct. The themes I'm using are the `deftheme`-style of theme.

I don't understand why customising terminal colours should affect this — with `TERM=xterm-256color`, Emacs should have access to a greater palette than just the usual 16 colours. In the output of `list-colors-display`, `black` is listed as `#000000` but displayed as `#151515`; there is, however, a `color-16` that is also listed as `#000000` and displayed properly. So Emacs is indeed capable of displaying `#000000`.

[image: Emacs GTK vs terminal comparison]

On the left is Emacs GTK, which displays the theme colours correctly. On the right is `emacs -nw` run in Gnome terminal, where all the colours are slightly different from what the theme specifies. The theme I've used for this picture is just an example; this happens with any theme. My full [config is on Github](https://github.com/detly/config-emacs/tree/5cb6c45eeb1982ae3a5e071eba06a76dbb122cef).

How can I get Emacs to display the correct theme colours in Gnome terminal without removing my customisation of the terminal palette?

Comment: Ha!  I can't even get my _font_ to show up the same in window and in terminal.  You should count your blessings. :)

Comment: @dg99 I just use the same one for everything :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple issues:

1) I believe that when you customize the "terminal colours", they overlap the first 16 color entries of the 256-colour palette.  So if emacs is telling the terminal to use colors 0-15, they will come out as whatever you have set that colour to actually be in your terminal preferences.  It doesn't appear to be affecting you specifically, but it is good to be aware of.

2) For the remaining 256 colors, I believe there are only 256 (maybe 241 if your terminal re-colored the first 16) colors that you [may choose from](http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html).

Unless you choose your GTK theme colors to match exact [colours that are available in the 256 palette](http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html), having them be identical is not going to be possible.  It looks like your emacs did a pretty good job of selecting the closest available colors of the 256 on its own.

If you want to see what I'm talking about in action, try downloading and running a script such as this [show-all-256-colors.py script](https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/2762225) and running it in your terminal.  I would wager that as you change your terminal colours, you'll see the entries `000` through `015` change correspondingly, while the remaining colors are always the same.

Comment: I was contemplating creating a new terminal profile with the "normal" colour scheme, to be used exclusively for emacs. But if I understand point #1 right, this probably won't help. Upon reflection it makes sense that a 256 colour palette won't be able to display the full range of possible colours expressed with the three-octet `#XXYYZZ` scheme.